# Ruby on Rails 5.2 - Ajax con formularios remotos?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

Hello when I add the comment in my application in the form that I have with ajax, I have to reload the browser to upload the comment. In the browser I get this error that I supposedly have in this file: –

comments.self-0ecbebc26b60f48a0ae217c9f7494fa695ba88045ceb80b23dc2ead883a15114.js:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

```
at comments.self-0ecbebc26b60f48a0ae217c9f7494fa695ba88045ceb80b23dc2ead883a15114.js:2

at comments.self-0ecbebc26b60f48a0ae217c9f7494fa695ba88045ceb80b23dc2ead883a15114.js:12
```

(anonymous) @ comments.self-

0ecbebc26b60f48a0ae217c9f7494fa695ba88045ceb80b23dc2ead883a15114.js:2
(anonymous) @ comments.self-

url=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2F&version=2.1.3&tag=threesixty&uuid=47607236-35D4-4155-B49E-4F5E90045A90:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)
rails-ujs.self-

551fbd47b981dacbb84a270f9123074caf39eb72aaf6f478ab597c6f81435e4b.js?body=1:212 POST http://localhost:3000/articles/10/comments 500 (Internal Server Error)
Rails.ajax @ rails-ujs.self-

551fbd47b981dacbb84a270f9123074caf39eb72aaf6f478ab597c6f81435e4b.js?body=1:212
Rails.handleRemote @ rails-ujs.self-

551fbd47b981dacbb84a270f9123074caf39eb72aaf6f478ab597c6f81435e4b.js?body=1:568
(anonymous) @ rails-ujs.self-551fbd47b981dacbb84a270f9123074caf39eb72aaf6f478ab597c6f81435e4b.js?body=1:169

The files that I have in the code, are these:

comments.coffe:

```
$(document).on "ajax:success", "form#comments-form", (ev,data)->
console.log data
$(this).find("textarea").val("")
$("#comments-box").append("<li> #{data.body} -  </li>")
```

$(document).on "ajax:error", "form#comments-form", (ev,data)->
    console.log data

_form.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for([@article,@comment], html: { id:"comments-form", :"data-type"=> 
 "json", multipart: true, remote: true }) do |f| %>

<% if @comment.errors.any? %>
<div id="error_explanation">
  <h2><%= pluralize(comment.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this 
   comment from 
  being saved:</h2>

  <ul>
  <% comment.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
    <li><%= message %></li>
  <% end %>
  </ul>
</div>
<% end %>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :body %>
  <%= f.text_area :body %>
</div>
<div class="actions">
  <%= f.submit %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you haven't loaded `jQuery` Try:

1. Make sure you have `gem 'jquery-rails'` in your `Gemfile`
2. Make sure you have the following in `app/assets/javascripts/application.js`

   `//= require jquery
   //= require jquery_ujs`

If that doesn't work you might try adding this to the top of your Coffeescript file:
`$(document).ready () ->`

It's hard to suggest anything more based on the information in your question, but this might be a quick fix.